# Javascript Fetch - Get data from server when ok = false

Tags: javascript, django

I want to make an `POST` request to my server using the `fetch` method. If the request was successfully, it returns status code `200` with data. If there was an error, it returns any status code except `200` with a `message`.

Here's my JS code:

```
class Ajax{
    static Post(url, data, success, error=null){
        const csrftoken = data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"];
        delete data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"];
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(response => {
                const data = response.json();
                if (response.ok){
                    return data
                } else {
                    throw {"name": "ResponseNotOkError", "message": data["message"], "status": response.status};
                }
            })
            .then(success)
            .catch(err => {
                if (error !== null){
                    error(err.message, err.status); // custom function
                } else {
                    TinyText.Create(err.message); // Showing error
                }
            });
    }
}
```

For debugging I inserted this into the first line after my ajax function in my Django project:

```
return JsonResponse({
    "message": "Blablablabla"
    }, status=400)
```

I don't know how to access that `message`.

Answer (score 1):

you can get body and status code like the following

```
fetch(url)
  .then(async (res) => ({
    status: res.status,
    body: await res.json()
  })).then(({ status, body }) => {
    console.log(status); // this is the status code
    console.log(body);   // this is json body 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check for the status code, if it wasn't 200 then throw the message. After throwing your error will go to the catch statement.

```
.then(response => {
            const data = response.json();
            if (response.status != 200)
                throw{"message": data.message}
            // ...  Carry on
        })
```